# Polymer paper-fab not showing its label

Tags: polymer

I have updated polymer to v0.4.2; after this update all `paper-fab` labels have been disappeared, and I cannot show any text inside them any more.

Here is a [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/KnCw6bQknGWliHJmjb6n?p=preview)

Is there any way to bring them back??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<polymer-element name="extended-fab" extends="paper-fab" attributes="label" noscript>
  <template>
    {{label}}
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<extended-fab label="label"></extended-fab>
```

you could also do

```
<polymer-element name="extended-fab" extends="paper-fab" noscript>
  <template>
    <content></content>
  </template>
</polymer-element>

<extended-fab>label</extended-fab>
```

Comment: i just forked your demo and made it work here. http://plnkr.co/edit/A5QFfizoAWib1NamzbvM?p=preview